# Hibernate @Sort / Sorted Set

Tags: hibernate, sorting, jboss, annotations

One Entity has a SortedSet. Hibernate now throws an Exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A sorted collection has to define @Sort: my.package.namespace.class.fieldname

However, there *is* no @Sort Annotation? Even the Namespace is not available...

Hibernate is provided by JBoss - may this be an old version or something?

How can Hibernate throw an Exception, asking for an Annotation, if the annotation is not there?
Even if it would be an old version of hibernate - who can Hibernate ask for something it has not inside its current Build?

Using Jboss AS 7.1 with hibernate "provided":

BOM: 1.0.0.Final

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${jboss.bom.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

edit: added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

still wondering why this is not part of hibernate itself, or why there is no dependency set on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `@Sort` annotation is part of `hibernate-core`, so it is part of hibernate itself.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/annotations/Sort.html

Comment: But it was unknown, until i added hibernate-annotations dependency... (unknown in Terms of "Namespace / Interface not available" - Hibernate itself ASKED to use that Annotation)

Comment: It wasn't in hibernate-core in version 3.3.2, but this is quite old (2009). In jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate there is no fixed version of hibernate. What version of hibernate do you use?